# How to add text to Cluster Force Layout bubbles

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add some text from the name field in my JSON file to each bubble in a cluster.

https://plnkr.co/edit/hwxxG34Z2wYZ0bc51Hgu?p=preview

I have added what I thought was correct attributes to the nodes with

```
node.append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
})
.attr("dx", -10)
.attr("dy", "5em")
.text(function (d) {
    return d.name
})
.style("stroke", "white");

    function tick(e) {
    node.each(cluster(10 * e.alpha * e.alpha))
    .each(collide(.5))
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var k = "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    return k;
})
```

}

Everything works fine except the labels.
What am I missing here?

Thanks
Kev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you will need to make a group like this:

```
  var node = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g").call(force.drag);//add drag to the group
```

To the group add circle.

```
var circles = node.append("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.cluster);
    })
```

To the group add text:

```
  node.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .attr("dx", -10)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    })
    .style("stroke", "white");
```

Add tween to the circle in  group like this:

```
  node.selectAll("circle").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * 5;
    })
    .attrTween("r", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.radius);
      return function(t) {
        return d.radius = i(t);
      };
    });
```

Now the tick method will translate the group and with the group the circle and text will take its position.

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cOrNokVYm9O5NXOKhYhF?p=preview)

Comment: A solution using groups is definitely more elegant.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, that makes much more sense to me, but now the clusters do not remain clusters when you grab a circle and drag it, the others do not follow, and it does not re-cluster.

Comment: the way you have made clusters was incorrect I have fixed it which was  root cause of the drag failure https://plnkr.co/edit/t6MsTWpWwI4VG1shqU2M?p=preview refer this for details https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658

Answer (score 3):

The problem: a `text` SVG element **cannot** be child of a `circle` SVG element.

The solution is creating another selection for the texts:

```
var nodeText = svg.selectAll(".nodeText")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .call(force.drag);
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qnx7CQox0ge89zBL9jxc?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, I read through the link you posted, particularly the "Learn what SVG elements can hold children", which lead me to https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html, some of which goes by me, but mostly sticks.

Comment: No worries, @Kevin. Please consider unmaking my answer and marking Cyril's answer as the correct one, because using groups is a more elegant solution (this is for the future readers).